# 'write一 アトリビュートがない' とエラーになってしまう

Tags: python

以下のコードを書いて英単語テストを作ろうとしたのですが、エラーが出てしまいました。
どうすれば解決するのでしょうか。環境はjupyter Notebook です。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-60260a1521a9> in <module>
     19     with open('英単語テスト_{:02d}.txt'.format(test_num +1),'w') as f:
     20 
---> 21         f.write一('第{}回英単語テスト\n\n'.format(test_num +1))
     22 
     23         for question_num in range(n_questions):

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'write一'
```

**コード**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import random

source = 'english_words.txt'

with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    english_words = [l.strip() for i, l in enumerate(data) if ((i%2) == 0)]
    jp_meanings = [l.strip() for i, l in enumerate(data) if ((i%2) != 0)]

words_dict = dict(zip(english_words,jp_meanings))

print(words_dict)

n_tests = 5
n_questions = 50
for test_num in range(n_tests):
    with open('英単語テスト_{:02d}.txt'.format(test_num +1),'w') as f:

        f.write一('第{}回英単語テスト\n\n'.format(test_num +1))

        for question_num in range(n_questions):
            question_word = random_choice(english_words)
            correct_answer = words_dict[question_word]

            meanings_copy = meanings.copy()
            meanings_copy.remove(correct_answer)
            wrong_answers = random.sample(meanings_copy,3)

            answer_options = [correct_answer] + wrong_answers

            random.shuffle(answer_options)

            f.write('問{}. {}\n\n'.format(question_num + 1,question_word))

            for i in range(4):
                f.write('{}.{}\n'.format(i + 1, answer_options[i]))
            f.write('\n\n')
```

Comment: 質問はいきなりコードを貼り付けるのではなく、まず言葉による説明を先にした方が読み手に親切かなと思いました。

Comment: @cubick ご指摘ありがとうございます。次回以降気を付けます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `f.write一('第{}回英単語テスト\n\n'.format(test_num +1))`

メソッド名が間違ってますね `write一`

Comment: ありがとうございます！